# Minify android app but do not obfuscate it

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

When I do not minify my app I reach the maximum method count and building the dex file fails. This can be avoided by enabling `minify` in `build.gradle`. The downside, however, is that now the code gets obfuscated. This is OK for the Release build but it is problematic for a Debug build.

Is there a way to tell gradle to minify a Debug build but not obfuscate it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, you can use ProGuard to minify debug builds.

The key is to use `-dontobfuscate` option in ProGuard configuration for debug build.

Use this setting in `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro', 
            'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
    }
}
```

Write your release ProGuard configuration to `proguard-rules.pro`.

Use the same configuration for release and debug. This way you ensure that no necessary code is stripped away. And debug minification doesn't break the build.

Add extra ProGuard config file `proguard-rules-debug.pro` for debug build. It should contain rules used only for debug. In this case add only:

```
-dontobfuscate
```

Comment: This approach is good if you need specific debug-only Proguard configuration, but for a simple "shrink, don't obfuscate" operation, @MrMaffen's answer below is the better option.

Answer (score 60):

```
minifyEnabled true
```

is just a shortcut for:

```
postprocessing {
    removeUnusedCode true
    obfuscate true
    optimizeCode true
}
```

So, if you want to minify without obfuscating, replace `minifyEnabled true` with:

```
postprocessing {
    removeUnusedCode true
    obfuscate false // <--
    optimizeCode true
}
```

Additionally, the compiler will complain if you have `shrinkResources true`. The equivalent postprocessing field is `removeUnusedResources true`, i.e:

```
postprocessing {
    removeUnusedCode true
    removeUnusedResources true // <--
    obfuscate false
    optimizeCode true
}
```

Contrary to other answers, `useProguard false` **does not disable obfuscation**; it changes the obfuscation engine from ProGuard to R8.

Comment: That's very interesting, can post documentation on this?  where do we find this info?

Comment: @JeffPadgett I read the source code for the Gradle plugin. I don't think there's any documentation for it unfortunately

Comment: I just saw it in the source code too, nice job figuring this out.  Very easy to read, make a lot of sense - I like it better than the minifyEnabled, actually, because here we can really modify it the way we want.  I hope they add this to the documentation.  Here is another good resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510109/what-is-postprocessing-block-inside-the-release-block-in-app-level-gradle-fi

Comment: For people using kts, prefix these properties with `is`, like `isRemoveUnusedCode`

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution is to add `minifyEnabled true` and `useProguard false` inside the build configuration. But code shrinking is not recommended for **debug** builds from official docs *Be aware that code shrinking slows down the build time, so you should avoid using it on your debug build if possible.*
Reference https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 5):

Tomik's answer is technically correct, but it doesn't support using [Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run) for your builds. As pointed out in the [official guide on code-shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#gradle-shrinker):

> Enable code shrinking with Instant Run If code shrinking is important
>   to you while incrementally building your app, try the experimental
>   code shrinker that's built into the Android plugin for Gradle. This
>   shrinker supports Instant Run, unlike ProGuard.
>
> You can configure the Android plugin shrinker using the same
>   configuration files as ProGuard. However, the Android plugin shrinker
>   does not obfuscate or optimize your code—it only removes unused code.
>   So you should use it for your debug builds only, and enable ProGuard
>   for your release builds so your release APK's code is obfuscated and
>   optimized.

So the proper solution would be to setup your debug build like this:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
}
```

This way the code in your debug build doesn't get optimized nor obfuscated, but will get shrunk. This also applies when using [Instant Run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run).

Comment: This was the better solution for me, running Android Studio 3.2.1. Adding a debug-only Proguard file would be good if I needed more fine-tuned configuration, but for a simple "shrink, don't obfuscate" command, Gradle was just fine.