# What is "postprocessing" block inside the 'release' block in app level gradle file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Below is the snipet of app level gradle file.

```
 buildTypes {
    release {

        postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources false
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode false
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Here, 'postprocessing' seems new in the gradle file. What does it mean?
Android studio shows error while adding 'setMinifyEnabled true' along with it.

Studio Error:
Error:The `setMinifyEnabled true` method cannot be used with together with the `postprocessing`

Comment: you don't need proguard in the postprocessing block though

Comment: Is it documented anywhere in the Android Developer website ?

Comment: The postprocessing block? Probably. But when you generate a project in AS it doesn't create the postprocessing block for proguard. So you don't need it to use proguard

Comment: @RikinPrajapati which version of AS are you using?

Comment: Android Studio 3.1 Canary 4

Comment: I tried opening the source code, strangely there's no comment from it. Maybe we need to wait until it hits beta, then Android team publish some documentation for it.

Comment: I created an issue for this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70522935.

Comment: @RikinPrajapati , @Zoe `postprocessing` block is simple and easy to configure alternative to `proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-android-optimize.txt`

Comment: That I understood, But It is strange that why it is not documented anywhere in developer website yet.

Comment: @RikinPrajapati I think it will be documented in the Android Developer website after release of Android Studio 3.1 Stable/RC. See my answer below

Answer (score 22):

`postprocessing` block (the new postprocessing DSL) is simple and easy to configure alternative to `proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-android-optimize.txt` (`proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-android-optimize.txt` generated at build time and stored in the build directory).

**1. proguard-rules.pro - your own rules**

```
buildTypes {
    release {            
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**2. proguard-android.txt - standard default rules**

```
buildTypes {
    release {            
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
```

**3. proguard-android-optimize.txt - optimized default rules**

```
buildTypes {
    release {            
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
    }
}
```

**4. proguard-android.txt - standard default rules, proguard-rules.pro - your own rules**

```
buildTypes {
    release {            
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**5. proguard-android-optimize.txt - optimized default rules, proguard-rules.pro - your own rules**

```
buildTypes {
    release {            
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**6. removeUnusedCode, removeUnusedResources, obfuscate, optimizeCode - simple and easy to configure default rules**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources false
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode false
        }
    }
}
```

**7. removeUnusedCode, removeUnusedResources, obfuscate, optimizeCode - simple and easy to configure default rules, proguard-rules.pro - your own rules**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources false
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode false
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**8. removeUnusedCode, removeUnusedResources, obfuscate, optimizeCode - simple and easy to configure default rules, proguard-defaults.txt - default rules (does not disable any actions, includes optimizations config, to be used with the new "postProcessing" DSL block)**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources false
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-defaults.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

**9. removeUnusedCode, removeUnusedResources, obfuscate, optimizeCode - simple and easy to configure default rules, proguard-defaults.txt - default rules (does not disable any actions, includes optimizations config, to be used with the new "postProcessing" DSL block), proguard-rules.pro - your own rules**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources false
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-defaults.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**Also you can use in postprocessing block PostprocessingOptions below:**

```
//Test ProGuard rule files
testProguardFile 'test-proguard-rules.pro'
testProguardFiles 'test-proguard-rules-1.pro', 'test-proguard-rules-2.pro'    
//ProGuard rule files to be included in the published AAR.
//These proguard rule files will then be used by any application project that consumes the AAR (if ProGuard is enabled).
//This is only valid for Library project. This is ignored in Application project.
consumerProguardFile 'consumer-proguard-rules.pro'    
consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-proguard-rules-1.pro', 'consumer-proguard-rules-2.pro'
```

**PostprocessingOptions.java from com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha08:**

```
/*
* Copyright (C) 2017 The Android Open Source Project
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

package com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl;

import static com.google.common.base.Verify.verifyNotNull;

import com.android.annotations.NonNull;
import com.android.annotations.Nullable;
import com.android.annotations.VisibleForTesting;
import com.android.build.gradle.ProguardFiles;
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.CodeShrinker;
import com.android.utils.HelpfulEnumConverter;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

/** DSL object for configuring postProcessing: removing dead code, obfuscating etc. */
public class PostprocessingOptions {
private static final String AUTO = "auto";
private static final HelpfulEnumConverter<CodeShrinker> SHRINKER_CONVERTER =
        new HelpfulEnumConverter<>(CodeShrinker.class);

@NonNull private final Project project;

private boolean removeUnusedCode;
private boolean removeUnusedResources;
private boolean obfuscate;
private boolean optimizeCode;

private List<File> proguardFiles;
private List<File> testProguardFiles;
private List<File> consumerProguardFiles;

@Nullable private CodeShrinker codeShrinker;

@Inject
public PostprocessingOptions(@NonNull Project project) {
    this(
            project,
            ImmutableList.of(
                    ProguardFiles.getDefaultProguardFile(
                            ProguardFiles.ProguardFile.NO_ACTIONS.fileName, project)));
}

@VisibleForTesting
PostprocessingOptions(@NonNull Project project, List<File> proguardFiles) {
    this.project = project;
    this.proguardFiles = Lists.newArrayList(proguardFiles);
    this.testProguardFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    this.consumerProguardFiles = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void initWith(PostprocessingOptions that) {
    this.removeUnusedCode = that.isRemoveUnusedCode();
    this.removeUnusedResources = that.isRemoveUnusedResources();
    this.obfuscate = that.isObfuscate();
    this.optimizeCode = that.isOptimizeCode();
    this.proguardFiles = Lists.newArrayList(that.getProguardFiles());
    this.testProguardFiles = Lists.newArrayList(that.getTestProguardFiles());
    this.consumerProguardFiles = Lists.newArrayList(that.getConsumerProguardFiles());
    this.codeShrinker = that.getCodeShrinkerEnum();
}

public boolean isRemoveUnusedCode() {
    return removeUnusedCode;
}

public void setRemoveUnusedCode(boolean removeUnusedCode) {
    this.removeUnusedCode = removeUnusedCode;
}

public boolean isRemoveUnusedResources() {
    return removeUnusedResources;
}

public void setRemoveUnusedResources(boolean removeUnusedResources) {
    this.removeUnusedResources = removeUnusedResources;
}

public boolean isObfuscate() {
    return obfuscate;
}

public void setObfuscate(boolean obfuscate) {
    this.obfuscate = obfuscate;
}

public boolean isOptimizeCode() {
    return optimizeCode;
}

public void setOptimizeCode(boolean optimizeCode) {
    this.optimizeCode = optimizeCode;
}

public List<File> getProguardFiles() {
    return proguardFiles;
}

public void setProguardFiles(List<Object> proguardFiles) {
    this.proguardFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object file : proguardFiles) {
        this.proguardFiles.add(project.file(file));
    }
}

public void proguardFile(Object file) {
    this.proguardFiles.add(project.file(file));
}

public void proguardFiles(Object... files) {
    for (Object file : files) {
        proguardFile(file);
    }
}

public List<File> getTestProguardFiles() {
    return testProguardFiles;
}

public void setTestProguardFiles(List<Object> testProguardFiles) {
    this.testProguardFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object file : testProguardFiles) {
        this.testProguardFiles.add(project.file(file));
    }
}

public void testProguardFile(Object file) {
    this.testProguardFiles.add(project.file(file));
}

public void testProguardFiles(Object... files) {
    for (Object file : files) {
        testProguardFile(file);
    }
}

public List<File> getConsumerProguardFiles() {
    return consumerProguardFiles;
}

public void setConsumerProguardFiles(List<Object> consumerProguardFiles) {
    this.consumerProguardFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object file : consumerProguardFiles) {
        this.consumerProguardFiles.add(project.file(file));
    }
}

public void consumerProguardFile(Object file) {
    this.consumerProguardFiles.add(project.file(file));
}

public void consumerProguardFiles(Object... files) {
    for (Object file : files) {
        consumerProguardFile(file);
    }
}

@NonNull
public String getCodeShrinker() {
    if (codeShrinker == null) {
        return AUTO;
    } else {
        return verifyNotNull(SHRINKER_CONVERTER.reverse().convert(codeShrinker));
    }
}

public void setCodeShrinker(@NonNull String name) {
    if (name.equals(AUTO)) {
        codeShrinker = null;
    } else {
        codeShrinker = SHRINKER_CONVERTER.convert(name);
    }
}

/** For Gradle code, not to be used in the DSL. */
@Nullable
public CodeShrinker getCodeShrinkerEnum() {
    return codeShrinker;
}
}
```

**ProguardFiles.java from com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha08:**

```
...
public enum ProguardFile {
    /** Default when not using the "postProcessing" DSL block. */
    DONT_OPTIMIZE("proguard-android.txt"),

    /** Variant of the above which does not disable optimizations. */
    OPTIMIZE("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),

    /**
     * Does not disable any actions, includes optimizations config. To be used with the new
     * "postProcessing" DSL block.
     */
    NO_ACTIONS("proguard-defaults.txt"),
    ;

    @NonNull public final String fileName;

    ProguardFile(@NonNull String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Is there any website to show all flags? Also, using the normal/optimized proguard option shows : "Cause: proguard-android-optimize.txt should not be used together with the new postprocessing DSL. The new DSL includes sensible settings by default, you can override this using `postprocessing { proguardFiles = []}`" . Does this mean it's used anyway, so no need to mention it? But "proguard-rules.pro" should be there, though, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I think all flags will be documented in the Android Developer website after release of Android Studio 3.1 Stable/RC. You can't use `postprocessing block` and `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt/proguard-android-optimize.txt')` together, but you can use `proguardFile/proguardFiles/testProguardFile/testProguardFiles/consumerProguardFile/consumerProguardFiles` with files with your own rules. I edited my answer above

Comment: Using my proguard file will also use Google's default one, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper See ProguardFiles.java and PostprocessingOptions.java. Default when not using the "postProcessing" DSL block: `proguard-android.txt`. Variant of the above which does not disable optimizations: `proguard-android-optimize.txt`. Does not disable any actions, includes optimizations config. To be used with the new "postProcessing" DSL block:
`proguard-defaults.txt`

Comment: @androiddeveloper  You **can** use `postprocessing block` and `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-defaults.txt')` together. For example, `postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources false
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-defaults.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The answer is that it will, or will not, use the default one, in case I set my own to be used?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, it will use the default one (`proguard-defaults.txt`), but: _Optimizations can be turned on and off in the 'postProcessing' DSL block. The configuration in the proguard-defaults.txt is applied if optimizations are enabled_.

Comment: So a common usage would be what you wrote on #7, with the ability to set each of the flags there, as needed. Setting all to true, it should use both my proguard rules and those of the optimized, built in one, right?

Comment: `postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources true
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-defaults.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }` 1. `proguard-defaults.txt` will be merged with `proguard-rules.pro`; 2. `removeUnusedCode` and `obfuscate` optimizations will be disabled in the proguard-merged.txt (result of 1.); 3. proguard-merged.txt will be applied;

Comment: Sorry , but it's very hard to read and understand what you write in comments this way. Is what I wrote correct, or not? What you wrote seems similar to what you wrote on #9 snippet in your answer.